# How to update chromedriver version to 35?

Tags: testing, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver version 2.10. I have update the version to 35. 
Could anyone provide how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chromedriver latest version is 2.10. You can check versions http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

We can update chrome version to 35 http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/57050/

Answer (score 3):

> Read on if your *webdriver-manager update* doesn't update chromedriver
>   to the latest.

I lost a few weeks pulling my hair around an issue I had with `"Unable to discover open pages"` and every time I would update the chromedriver, it would update to `version 2.22` for chromedriver and I believe the selenium server to `v2.53`. 
My problem wasn't really with the selenium server so v2.53 was fine.

```
Issue was with chromedriver v2.22.
```

Eventhough [this chromdriver link](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) showed that there was a latest version of 2.24, `'webdriver-manager update'` would NOT pick up that latest version, it would only grab version 2.22 of the chrome driver.

> How did I go around this?

Simply run the command below after [you check this link](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) for which version of chromedriver you want to update to; for instance, I wanted v2.24 so I ran the command below:

> webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.24

If you check your location: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\`

You should see that the desired chromedriver was downloaded there; if it's not there, read the command prompt logs and it'll tell you where it downloaded your chromdriver files.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Did we ever get  a fix for this that does not involve us having to manually put the .exe file there. I had to do something similar, but if someone pulled my project they would have to remember my hack..

Comment: so my issue is I am using webdriver-manager and it currently uses chromerdriver 2.22 and you I need 2.24 I had to copy 2.24 into the directory and change it's name to make it believe it was 2.22.. I did put on issue on the github for webdriver-manager

Comment: Hey @Maccurt I updated my answer above; that should fix your issues now!

Comment: I really appreciate it, because all my test were failing after a chrome upgrade, and I actually spend time looking at my code thinking I broke it. Let me try it, I HIGHLY APPRECIATE YOU GETTING BACK TO ME. I did put an issue on webdriver-manager on github

Comment: @Maccurt Glad it worked for you; been there as well so I help whenever I get a chance, thanks :)

Comment: I still couldn't figure out, from where the webdriver-manager is getting the chrome driver version (the version 2.22, which it was looking for)

Answer (score 1):

ChromeDriver and Chrome browser are two separate applications.

ChromeDriver is an implementation of [WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), an API which allow us to control browser behaviour. 
In ChromeDriver case it's used to control Chrome browser of *some version*.

As you noted, ChromeDriver last version is [2.10](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

The version of the Chrome browser which is controlled by the ChromeDriver, got separate development flow and get updated independently to ChromeDriver, [Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/) version in your case is 35.

In conclusion, don't mix the two applications, they different.
P.S. it's important to note, that in some occasion when new browser version released, the according driver got updated to in order to update it's behaviour according to the new developments of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between chromedriver and chrome as a browser.

The version of chromedriver is not connected with version of chrome browser but you'd better use the latest version of chromedriver.